# How to use the Achievements module?

Tags: users, 7

I want to create some kind of challenges for users. And when it is fulfilled the user is able to unlock a new level and gain some kind of victory say in terms of a new theme, i.e, after completion of that challenge the user is awarded a new theme which the user can set as their theme.

I want to do this using the [Achievements](https://www.drupal.org/project/achievements) module. However there seems to be almost no documentation available, so I'm looking for ideas on how to proceed.

**Note**: I have basic understanding of php and have created few basic modules as described in drupal.org.

Comment: Are you able to program?  The module's documentation page states that **Creating achievements requires custom code**.

Comment: i have basic understanding of php...and have created few basic modules as described in drupal.org

Comment: Sure. Will keep in mind. Thanks for the module :) Have edited and tagged the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Achievements](https://www.drupal.org/project/achievements) module is indeed a possible solution to implement the gamification facilities you are considering. However it does require Drupal development skills (you really need to write your own custom module for it).

If you don't have the required skills for it, or just don't want to do such coding (or don't want to hire somebody with such skills), then you may want to look at the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module (disclosure: I'm its maintainer) as a possible alternative. To start using it only requires typical administration tasks (configuration), though it does come with various hooks also for custom module development (if you want to).

For more details about the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module, refer to my answer to "[How to implement gamification in a Drupal site and award incentives?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/168)".

Answer (score 4):

The comments and example code in the documentation: [achievements.api.php](http://drupalcode.org/project/achievements.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/achievements.api.php) show how to create a new achievement.

There is no administration interface, you must create a module and use the hooks described in the above link to create new achievements.